# What is the correct way to send data from Arduino HC-05 Bluetooth to Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, embedded, buffer

I am trying to send float data from Arduino HC-05 to Android. My android code to receive data is

```
byte buffer[];
            buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes = dataInputStream.read(buffer);
            if(bytes > 0) {
                String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.i(TAG, "listen: " + message);
            }
```

I am unable to parse the byte buffer back to float. I tried googling but no help. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

The string I get after this is some unknown characters with question mark.

Below in my Aurdino code:

```
double duration, distance,FrontSensor,LeftSensor;
```

void loop()
{

```
SonarSensor(trigPinFront, echoPinFront);
FrontSensor = distance;
if(FrontSensor > 30) {
  FrontSensor = FrontSensor / 30;
  BTserial.write(FrontSensor);
Serial.println(FrontSensor);
}
delay(1000);
```

}

The Output I get is:
[image: Output I get]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code instead:

```
//create new class for connect thread
  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;


    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes; 

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

          }
        }
    }
```

This is working for me to get bluetooth information from an Arduino! :)

**EDIT:** To convert the values from doubleto string in arduino use:

`dtostrf(floatVar, minStringWidthIncDecimalPoint, numVarsAfterDecimal, charBuf);`

Comment: I am trying to get the float value from the buffer read using input stream.  I get the String input correctly. but when I send float or integer data it gets converted to some random characters with question marks

Comment: I use floats and integrers aswell, and with the code before I'm able to get the correct variables, it's weird

Comment: I added the image of the Output.

Comment: Yes I did. Same Output. Did you check the aurdino code? It is sending double value to android. Is it a problem ?

Comment: Now that I've checked my code I convert the float values to String! Use `dtostrf` in your arduino code, so the double is converted to string

Comment: But SoftwareSerial.write() does not accept String as argument. It accepts charArray as argument.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful.

```
int charsRead = 0;
char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (mRun)
{
    charsRead = in.read(buffer);
    serverMessage = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
        if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
             Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
        }
    serverMessage = null;
}
```

Comment: Not Working. Weird output I am getting.